# How can I get psql to work in ubuntu from shell: $ psql -U admin -d mydb

Tags: postgresql

Apparently this is a pretty hard question to ask because, simple as it is, no one seems to have answered it.

I have PostgreSQL running on ubuntu 12.10 server (no GUI).

My goal - my question - is to create a database named "mydb" and a user "admin" such that I can give this command as an ordinary user from the shell and connect to the database:

> $ psql -U admin -d mydb

But I cannot find the answer to this anywhere.

I can log in as user *postgres* by su'ing and running the *psql* command:

```
$ sudo su -m postgres
postgres@baseubu1210dev:~$ psql
psql (9.1.7)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I have figured out how to create a database named "mydb" and a user "admin" such that:

```
postgres=# \du
 Role name |                 List of roles Attributes       | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

I have *not* figured out how to make sure that user "admin" can connect to the "mydb" database - perhaps someone with such privileges doesn't need to?  [As I write, I notice that I should probably revoke Superuser privileges from admin.]

And what I really want to know is how to connect from a *regular user's shell*:

```
$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

There are surely unwritten assumptions about running postgreSQL that I'm misunderstanding, but a couple of hours of searching, looking at tutorials, etc., has not solved the problem.  I'll be perfectly happy if someone says this has already been answered, especially if it has.  I assume and hope that the answer is simple and appreciate your help.

Thanks,
ge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the error-message, it seems that the authentication-settings have not been properly set.

Besides the settings in the database itself, PostgreSQL also uses a configuration file (pg_hba.conf) that specifies what authentication-mechanisms can be used per user, host and database. You can specify that users can only connect via password/md5 password or even 'no authentication required'

Currently your configuration probably uses 'Peer' authentication for all users, which simply means: Only allow that user if it is the currently logged-in user (e.g. your shell-user should also be called 'admin'). From your question, this is *not* what you want, you'll probably want to use password or md5 authentication mechanism.

I think these pages will give you the answer you need:

http://web.archive.org/web/20131001194046/http://blog.deliciousrobots.com/2011/12/13/get-postgres-working-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/ (archived version)

Official documentation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Remember to reload postgresql after modifying the pg_hba.conf file!

**update**

The original blog-post I referred to is now offline, the link now points to an archived version. Thanks to @O_the_Del for reporting.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have to run out but will go over your answer and links when I get back.

Comment: Hope it works. PostgreSQL is a great database, but has quite a steep learning-curve in some situations

Comment: thaJeztah - I can't seem to write down what I did in a comment, but basically, your advice worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Comments don't allow 'code' blocks, but you can always append it to your original question so that others can learn. Please mark the question 'answered' :)

Comment: According to Google - I can't find it on stackoverflow.com - I'm supposed to see a checkmark that I can click on to mark my question as answered, but I simply don't see it?  I suspect I've blocked something, but I am using chrome, my more open browser (FF is locked down pretty tight).

Comment: Now I see it - hidden in plain sight!!  Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Blog post link is now dead.

Answer (score 5):

On Debian, PostgreSQL listens by default on localhost, so if you have a rule in pg_hba.conf which allows TCP/IP connections then you can use the -h parameter to match that rule:

```
psql -U admin -h localhost mydb
```